# Get UI Elements of application opened by Finder using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

```applescript
set classNames to {}
tell application "Finder"
    tell front window of (first application process whose frontmost is true)
        set uiElems to entire contents as list
    end tell
end tell
```

When I run this in Script Editor, it returns:

```applescript
{group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", pop up button 1 of group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", pop up button 2 of group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", checkbox 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", checkbox 2 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", checkbox 3 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", busy indicator 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", static text "Running…" of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", text area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", splitter 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", static text "Result" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", text area 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", scroll bar 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", splitter 1 of splitter group 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 1 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 2 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 3 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 4 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", group 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", checkbox 1 of group 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", checkbox 2 of group 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", static text "—" of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 1 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 2 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", button 3 of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", menu button "Edited" of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", image "test" of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder", static text "test" of window "test" of application process "Script Editor" of application "Finder"}
```

But when I try to run the script as an app and try to open an application through Finder the error is:

```
Can’t get window 1 of application process 1 whose frontmost = true. Invalid index. (-1719)
```

Can someone help with this? I am new to AppleScript and don't have a clue.

Comment: When you run your application, it will be frontmost, and an error will be thrown if it doesn't have any windows.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get the ui elements of finder application or ui elements of an application opened by finder.

Comment: AppleScript doesn't have a way to monitor what the Finder is doing.  Are you wanting to watch for application launches?  What kind of output are you planning to use?

Comment: Right now i just want ui elements of a finder application. would that be possible?

Comment: There is a [script on MacScripter](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=147645#p146903) that might be close to what you are trying to do.